# Не устанавливается значение в текстовом поле

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Имеется поле

```
<input type="text" name="num_cart"  />
```

Имеется кнопка

```
<input type="button" name="seach" id="seach" value="Поиск карточки" onsubmit='return seach(num_cart);'/>    </td>
```

По нажатии кнопки идет поиск по БД

```
if (@$_POST['seach']){
$seach=mysql_query("select * from cart where num_cart='{$num_cart}'") or die (mysql_error);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($zapros) ){
$num_cart=$row['num_cart'];
$otdel=$row['otdel']; }
```

Результат должен прописаться в поле

```
<input type="text" name="otdel" />
```

Как на яве сделать эту прописку?

```
function seach(num_cart){
forma.otdel.value=otdel;
}
```

Вот эта штука не работает.
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: оформи пожалста, а то глаза разбегаются

Comment: Не называйте javascript "явой".. мой вам совет..

Answer (score 1):

document.GetElementByName("otdel").value

Comment: Правильнее будет:

    document.getElementsByName("otdel")[0].value

Comment: Да. Прошу прощения за безграмотность)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать ajax для поиска (если вы хотите избежать перезагрузки страницы). В случае успешного ответа в callback функции производить запись нужного инпута. А сейчас у вас при сабмитте вызывается javascript функция, которая находит элемент и записывает в него какую-то переменную, которая должна приходить в ответе с сервера.

Answer (score 0):

1) Подключите jquery.
2) Напишите функцию для отправки данных на сервер на js, что-то вроде:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function get_otdel() {
        var options = {
            url: 'path/to/php/file.php',
            data: 'num_cart=' + $("#num_cart").val(),
            // добавьте id к вашему полю  
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#otdel").html(msg); // id ко второму полю  
            }
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
}
```

Собственно, останется только на пхп сделать поиск и возврат ответа.

Comment: три раза с помощью вашего редактора пытался сделать красиво. Не получилось :(

Comment: В редакторе есть дефект: после списка код не подхватывается.

Comment: К слову, во время комментирования ответов, редактор бы тоже прикрутить...